# How can I validate a textarea with pre-populated data?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea, ejs

I'm trying to validate a textarea with some pre-populated data.

On an edit view I have a textarea with some data in between the textarea closing tags.

**UPDATE**: The comments are displayed via an array, not sure how to edit a specific element within an array.

**EJS (HTML) Markup:**

```
<div class="collapse" id="collapseEdit<%= comment._id %>">
    <div style="margin: 15px 0;">
      <form id="edit-comment-form<%= comment._id %>" action="/places/<%= campground._id %>/comments/<%= comment._id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST">
        <div class="edit-comment-container">

          <!--Textarea Input Field Problem-->
          <textarea class="comment-edit-input" id="comment-edit-inputfield" name="comment[text]" rows="5" cols="70"><%= comment.text %></textarea>

          <button class="button submit" id="comment-edit-button">Edit comment</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**What I have done:**

To validate the textarea I tried checked for a value of null but this input does not accept a value, I then modified it the check for innerHTML but that didn't work either. I'm out of ideas how this can be validated via javascript, and no I'm not using required.

**What I'm trying to do:**

All I'm trying to do is if the textarea is empty add the disabled property to the field and modified the opacity. If the field is empty it should do the opposite to the invalid logic.

**This is my current version of the javascript validation :**

```
(() => {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 

        const editCommentInput = document.querySelector("#comment-edit-inputfield");     
        const editCommentButton = document.querySelector("#comment-edit-button");


        /* 
        Submit button logic:
        - By default the submit button is disabled so users cant just click the button and trigger the required message
        - The required atribute is there as a backup
        */
       editCommentButton.disabled = true;
       editCommentInput.required = true;

        const editCommentInputEvents = function () {
            if (editCommentInput.innerHTML == "") {
                editCommentButton.style.opacity = "0.5";
                editCommentButton.disabled=true ;
            } else {
                editCommentButton.style.opacity = "1";
                editCommentButton.disabled=false ;        
            }
        };

        /* 
        Event listerns for the comment input event:
        - Multiple events attached to the commentinput event
        - No need for Jquery
        - This could probably be improved 
        */
        window.addEventListener("keyup", editCommentInputEvents, false);
        window.addEventListener("keydown", editCommentInputEvents, false);
        window.addEventListener("keypress", editCommentInputEvents, false);
    });
})();
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated :)

Cheers,

Alex

Comment: what does the "editCommentInput.innerHTML" output if you log it in the console?

Comment: Nothing gets outputted which is weird as it should be outputting the comment text.

Comment: have you tried "editCommentInput.value" text area usually works a little differently then the other inputs

Comment: Textarea doesn't have a value, I tried this before but yeah value isn't a valid property in textarea not a clue why as its just a large input field lol

Comment: "const editCommentInput = document.querySelector("#comment-edit-inputfield"); " is this retrieving the correct element?

Comment: Yeah it is, the input was outputted to the console with all the properties assigned to it.

Comment: I only just remembered its an array of comments so the ID is on each of the edit field. That's causing the issue, not exactly sure how to solve this then grr.

Comment: ok if its an array of comments then get all the elements using `each('.CLASSNAME')` and then check `val()` of each element and then apply your intended style. `val()` is a property you should be using to get textarea value